# Socket.IO-objc Error Sending Messages To Node.js Server

Tags: ios, websocket, socket.io

I'm using socket.IO-objc in my project with Node.js and socket.io on the server. It connects to the server but does not seem to him the "message" event on the server side when I send the message using socket.IO-obj:

Client:

```
- (void)socketIODidConnect:(SocketIO *)socket
{   
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                   @"name": @"Josh",
                                   @"type": @"sometype",
                                   @"value": @"someValue"
                                };   

    NSLog(@"socket.io connected");

    [socketIO sendJSON: parameters]
}
```

Server:

```
  client.on('message', function(data){

        console.log('Received message: ' + data);

    });
```

It never Logs out the message inside console.log.
Is there something I'm missing? I would really appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Is your dictionary being created ? I would use dictionary withobjects forkeys.

Comment: NSDictionary *gameParameters = [NSDictionary     dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    email, @"email",
                                    type, @"type",
                                    value, @"value",
                                    @"gameParameters", @"command"
                                    , nil];                             This still doesn't work.